# How to get auto complete values into another object using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help. I need to get auto-complete values using google API in Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $element) {
  $scope.data = {};
  var placeAutoCompleteInput = $element[0].querySelector('#place');
  var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(placeAutoCompleteInput, {types: ['(cities)']});
 console.log('autocomplete',placeAutoCompleteInput);
  $scope.data.keyDown = function($event) {
    console.log("keyDown", $event);

  }
});
```

Here after typing in text box i am getting the values in drop down list but i need to assign those drop down fetched values to another variable.Here is [my full code](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWrmdODRz4q5QQmbMtqL?p=preview). Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> This Sample can helps you to figure out how can use google map auto complete on angularJs
>
> i used angular-google-places-autocomplete component you can find it on githup

```
 <input type="text" g-places-autocomplete ng-model="place" />
 <h5>Result:</h5>
 <pre>{{place | json}}</pre>
```

[plnkr preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/gwVzgOeqwNd5kpEMNSBA?p=preview)